# Getting automated raw recording in zoom windows SDK

Tags: r, windows, zoom-sdk, videosdk.live

"How can I initiate local recording immediately upon joining a meeting, and how can I enable automatic access granting for local recording in the Zoom SDK?"

I'm working on integrating the Zoom SDK into my application and I'm looking to achieve two specific functionalities. First, I want to initiate local recording immediately upon joining a Zoom meeting using the Zoom SDK. Second, I need to enable access granting for local recording within the application.

For the first part, I've initialized the Zoom SDK and successfully joined meetings, but I'm unsure how to trigger local recording automatically as soon as I join a meeting.

Regarding the second part, I want to provide users with the ability to grant or revoke access for local recording within my application. I'd like to know how to configure access settings for local recording programmatically using the Zoom SDK.

Any guidance or code examples related to these functionalities would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!